# IIS7.5 wordpress compression won't work

Tags: web-server, iis-7

Running wordpress on IIS I can not access my Backend. I get

```
The page you are trying to view cannot be shown because it uses an invalid or unsupported form of compression.
```

I do not have to many experience with IIS than I was trying to debug this error with fiddler which shows me UNGZip failed

```
"Request failed: The magic number in GZip header is not correct. Make sure you are passing in a GZip stream."
```

What does it mean?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're having a problem with HTTP compression: it doesn't seem to be working correctly.

Try going into the IIS web site and disable compression for both static and dynamic content.